# How do I know if django model instance was modified?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a code like that:

```
# ...
obj = Model.objects.get(pk=2342)
if foo:
    obj.foo = 'bar'
if bar:
    obj.bar = 'baz'
obj.save()
```

Is there a good way to find out if the model instance was modified in order to prevent saving it each time the code runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical pattern is to do something like:

```
model = Model.objects.get(pk=2342)
dirty = False
if foo:
    model.foo = 'bar'
    dirty = True
if bar:
    model.bar = 'baz'
    dirty = True

if dirty:
    model.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just diff the 'snapshot' instance w/ current model instance field-by-field, you could get the `snapshot` through `copy.copy(obj)` or `model_cls.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)`.

Also you could simply compare the dumped versions:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer
dump = Serializer.serialize([obj])
...
changed = dump == Serializer.serialize([obj])
```

Normally, tweak your code is easiest:

```
obj = Model.objects.get(pk=2342) # 'obj' is better than 'model', IMO
changed = False
if foo:
    ...
    obj.foo = 'bar'
    changed = True
if bar:
    ...
    obj.bar = 'baz'
    changed = True
if changed:
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django performs this check internally. An sql query wont be fired unless the model has actually changed.

**UPDATE**

This answer is wrong. My bad. I confused this with something else.

Comment: +1. Leave that check to Django unless you have very compelling reasons  to do so.

Comment: I don't think so. Can you provide some proof? Or have you mixed it up w/ `has_changed` checking of the Django form?

Comment: I don't think so either. Can you show on which line this check is handled [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py#L467)?

Comment: Furthermore, this logic is incorrect because it's the DB backend which maintains the consistency, not the model instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a more abstracted way, look at the documentation for the model method [`from_db()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.from_db), which is a hook called when data is loaded into the model instance from the database. With this method, you can cache the original value of a field as it is loaded, and then compare that to the current value in the `save()` method.

Example (note, I haven't actually tested this code):

```py
class SaveIfModified(models.Model):
    foo = models.TextField()

    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):
        instance = super().from_db(db, field_names, values)
        # caveat: deferred values won't appear here
        if "foo" in field_names:
            instance._foo = values[field_names.index("foo")]
        return instance

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.foo == getattr(self, "_foo", None):
            return
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```